# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, runtime

So I was making discord bot and everything seemed to be successful, until I stopped programm and started getting this error (yes... kinda big):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DsBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DsBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DsBots\bot.py", line 30, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DsBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DsBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DsBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DsBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DsBots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 304, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000026E2673BD90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

So I found out that the problem is in authorization, and maybe security, or maybe an error in code causes bot to `logout()`.
I found many same questions, but many of them was asked because of undetected syntax error.
Any suggestions?...
Edit: Sorry, forgot to post code. Here it is:

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
GUILD = os.getenv("DISCORD_GUILD")

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
    guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, name=GUILD)
    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})\n'
    )
    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')

async def on_message(message):
    print(message)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: ```TOKEN``` and ```GUILD``` are fine, I'm using ```.env``` file to define them... Or maybe there is problem in that?

Comment: `LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.` means that the token is in fact incorrect. Check the value of `print(TOKEN)` (don't post it here of course) to make sure it's actually correct. If that doesn't work, go to the developer portal and make a new token and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was because I was writting my `TOKEN` and `GUILD` in `.env` file in `{}`/`""` (so it looked like `DISCORD_TOKEN="token"` or `DISCORD_TOKEN={token}`). But `.env` file *always* writes variables in `string` type. I didn't knew that, so I was getting `LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.` (thanks to Eric Jin) because of my `TOKEN` and `GUILD` was with `{}`.
The problem solution was very simple:
Old code (`.env` file):

```
DISCORD_TOKEN="token"
DISCORD_GUILD="guild"
```

New code:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=token
DISCORD_GUILD=guild
```

(yes...)